# Question About Proving that $\mathbb Z_p^\times$ Is Cyclic

Tags: group-theory

> **Statement 1**:  Let $p$ be prime and that $m$ divides $p - 1$.  If there exists an element in $\mathbb Z_p^\times$ with order $m$, then the number of elements in $\mathbb Z_p^\times$ with order $m$ equals $\varphi(m)$.  The proof is as follows:
>
> Let $c$ be an element with order $m$.  Because the polynomial $x^m - 1 = 0 \mod p$ has at most $m$ roots, and each power of $c$ satisfies the polynomial, the solution set is $\{ \, 1, c \ldots c^{m-1} \, \}$.  The following equality shows that the number of elements with order $m$ is $\varphi(m)$.
>   $$\{ \, a \in \mathbb Z_p^\times : \# a = m \, \} = \{ \, c^i : (i, m) = 1 \, \}$$
>
> **Statement 2**:  $\mathbb Z_p$ has at most $1$ subgroup of a given size.  The proof is as follows:
>
> Take a subgroup $H$ of $\mathbb Z_p^\times$ with size $m$.  Because of Lagrange, the order of each $c \in H$ divides $m$.  Thus, $H$ is a subset of the solution set to the polynomial $x^m - 1 = 0 \mod p$.  Since there are at most $m$ roots to the polynomial, $H$ equals the entire set of the solution set.  Therefore, any $H'$ with size $m$ equals the solution set which equals $H$.

Both statements use the fact that the polynomial $x^m - 1 = 0$ has at most $m$ roots in $\mathbb Z_p$.  But while statement (1) spells out the solution set of the polynomial, statement (2) just argues that $A \subseteq B$ and $|A| = |B| = n \rightarrow A = B$.  I can see that the argument in (2) will not work in (1).  But can I prove (2) by mimicking the proof in (1)?

Take $c \in H$, so $S = \{ \, 1, c \ldots c^{m-1} \, \}$ is the solution set to the polynomial $x^m - 1 = 0 \mod p$.  By the definition of a subgroup, $S \subset H$.  Take $a \in H$; $a^m - 1 = 0$ since the order of $a$ divides $m$.  So $a \in S$ also.  This also proves that $H$ equals the solution set of the polynomial.

Comment: The error in your last paragraph is in assuming that   if $ x^m-1=0$  has a solution in the field $ Z_p$  then there exists $ c$ with $c^m-1=0 $ and $c^j -1 \ne 0$ for $1\le j<m$.  But this is what is to be proved for the case .$ m=p-1.$

Answer (score 0):

We can observe that each valid $c^k$ generates the group, i.e. instead of 
$\{1,c,\dots,c^{m-1}\}$ use $\{1,c^k,\dots,c^{k(m-1)}\}$. This produces exactly the same set for any $k$ and so the set is unique.